# Problems with layering sprites in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have been building a simple game using the pygame library for python. Here is a link to the repository.
https://github.com/stmfunk/alienExplorer

The issue I am having is with predictably overlaying sprites on top of each other. The clouds in this code are seemingly placed randomly above and below the alien. Although this behaviour is actually desirable in this example I'd like to know why it is behaving randomly and how can I make it behave as I want it too in future. I plan on adding objects which I want to remain in the background in future. 
Thanks for the help! 
Also I'm not sure if it is best practise to insert code directly or to link a repository so I'd appreciate it if somebody gave me advice on that.

Comment: In the future, you should put all relevant code in the question and link the source in case you left something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the technicalities, but what I have noticed from my own personal experiences is that sprites in the same group will always be ordered randomly. I assume that in the code above all the clouds are in one group and the alien in another and a third group containing all them (and if not, then I would suggest that that is an elegant way of doing it, especially to solve your problem). The solution with your problem above would be to instead of `draw`ing the group with everything in it, `draw` the individual groups in order of layers (`draw` the ones at the bottom first and then go up)